# Efficiency of Javascript Animation, clearRect()?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

in preparation for the fall of Flash, I'm attempting to transition between AS3 and Javascript.

However, some things confuse me (probably due to lack of knowledge). In Flash, I could create and explicitly modify the physical properties of objects I drew on the stage. In Canvas/HTML5, I can use `fillText()` and `fillRect()`, but I can't "animate" without having to clear the entire stage first then redraw everything, which strikes me as really inefficient. In addition to this, I don't have explicit access to these objects so I can modify their physical properties without having to delete everything in the first place.

How should I approach this differently?

Comment: `which strikes me as really inefficient` Flash also draws images this way by clearing the screen everytime, actually.

Comment: You can use [KinecticJS](http://kineticjs.com/) or other similar frameworks which lets you draw and animate on `canvas` easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all bitmaps you see animated the bitmap has to be cleared or overwritten, including Flash.

The difference is that Flash takes care of it for you while on canvas you have to take care of this yourself or use a library such as [Kinect](http://kineticjs.com/) which can smooth the transition from Flash to HTML5 Canvas.

As for efficiency, `clearRect()` is the second most efficient thing to clear the canvas. A faster way (in some browsers at least) is by setting `canvas.width = canvas.width;`. But I won't recommend it for two reasons:

1. It's "hackish".
2. It is not working like that in all browsers (Safari being one last time I checked).

Instead of `clearRect()` you can use `drawImage()` which is fast too as long as no scaling takes place. This is of course only useful if you intend to fill the background with image (or even an off-screen canvas).

And there is `fillRect()` which is not really intended for this use and is the slowest of these.

Combine this with `requestAnimationFrame` and you will have the most efficient combination in this context. That being said: the bottleneck with Canvas is really JavaScript itself so this is where I recommend adding effort to make the code efficient. There are many impressive demos out there using only canvas.